# Parsing JSON response when returned as Array

Tags: java, android, json, gson, okhttp

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
```

This is the error I continue to get while attempting to parse my incoming JSON response data. I'm utilizing the OkHttp library to create and call, and the API I'm getting results from returns everything in an Array as follows:

```
    [
      {
        "id": 4256,
        "image_url": "https://cdn.pandascore.co/images/league/image/4256/OMEN_Challenger_Series_2019.png",
        "live_supported": false,
        "modified_at": "2019-10-30T10:02:42Z",
        "name": "OMEN Challenger",
        "series": [
          {
            "begin_at": "2019-11-01T03:30:00Z",
            "description": null,
            "end_at": null,
            "full_name": "2019",
            "id": 1932,
            "league_id": 4256,
            "modified_at": "2019-10-30T09:11:40Z",
            "name": null,
            "prizepool": "50000 United States Dollar",
            "season": null,
            "slug": "cs-go-omen-challenger-2019",
            "winner_id": null,
            "winner_type": null,
            "year": 2019
          }
        ],
        "slug": "cs-go-omen-challenger",
        "url": "https://omengaming.co/omen_cs/",
        "videogame": {
          "current_version": null,
          "id": 3,
          "name": "CS:GO",
          "slug": "cs-go"
        }
      },
      {...},
      {...},
      {...},
      {...},
    ]
```

I found a lot of folks recommending Gson to parse it into a custom class, but the following code, in theory, should work and it isn't. The parsing doesn't even begin due to it expecting `BEGIN_OBJECT` and it being `BEGIN_ARRAY`:

```
String jsonData = response.body().string();
Gson gson = new Gson();
EventInfo test = gson.fromJson(jsonData, EventInfo.class);

class EventInfo {

    String imageURL;
    String name;
    JSONArray series;

}
```

Comment: In your response you are getting List<EventInfo> not just EventInfo. That's why you are getting expecting BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to parse it into an object. But in your response, you can clearly see that it's a list. The parent POJO should have been a list. And inside that list, you should have created another POJO.

Comment: It's interesting because I"d been using the method to parse it as a `List<EventInfo>` and still had the error, just in a different spot. The original issue was trying to parse `series` as a `JSONArray`. Full solution being added to the post as we speak! Thank you for encouraging me to give the `List<>` another go. --KH

Answer (score 0):

In your response parent is found as **array** but you need to add **first parent** as JSON **object** and child as a array or object.

You need response like this

```
{
    "YourArrayName":[
        "YourChildObjName":{
            "id": 4256,
            "image_url": "https://cdn.pandascore.co/images/league/image/4256/OMEN_Challenger_Series_2019.png",
            "live_supported": false,
            "modified_at": "2019-10-30T10:02:42Z",
            "name": "OMEN Challenger",
            "series": [
                {
                    "begin_at": "2019-11-01T03:30:00Z",
                    "description": null,
                    "end_at": null,
                    "full_name": "2019",
                    "id": 1932,
                    "league_id": 4256,
                    "modified_at": "2019-10-30T09:11:40Z",
                    "name": null,
                    "prizepool": "50000 United States Dollar",
                    "season": null,
                    "slug": "cs-go-omen-challenger-2019",
                    "winner_id": null,
                    "winner_type": null,
                    "year": 2019
                }
            ],
            "slug": "cs-go-omen-challenger",
            "url": "https://omengaming.co/omen_cs/",
            "videogame": {
                "current_version": null,
                "id": 3,
                "name": "CS:GO",
                "slug": "cs-go"
            }
        },
        {...},
        {...},
        {...},
        {...},
    ]
}
```

I hope this can help You!

Thank You

Comment: Thank you for this! Unfortunately I don't have any control over the API, but I found the solution. I had a 2-part problem, actually. :)

Comment: @KevinHaube OK.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out. Originally I was receiving the same error at a later point; namely when it got to the `series` key value in the first JSONObject. The original error occurred because I was trying to parse `series` as a `JSONArray`, rather than a `List<JSONObject>` The corrections are below:

```
String jsonData = response.body().string();
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<EventInfo>>() {}.getType();
List<EventInfo> test = gson.fromJson(jsonData, listType);
```

And the EventInfo class:

```
class EventInfo {

    String imageURL;
    String name;
    List<JSONObject> series;

}
```

Thank you for the advice everyone!